# Simple Python Proxy server that handle POST requests

Tags: python, post, proxy

I am trying to build a simple proxy server in Python that serves as the middle person that monitors and retrieves all the requests/traffic that is passed between my web browser and the Internet.  I found the following code:

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import urllib

PORT = 1234

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)

httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), Proxy)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But the example only handles GET requests.  Is there a way for the proxy server to handle the POST requests traffic from the browser as well? Thank you so much for your help!  :)

Answer (score 2):

just like you implemented `do_GET`, you can also implement `do_POST` in your `Proxy` class. This should probably work. You can refer [this](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997).

Comment: what should go in as the parameter for self.wfile.write()?  thanks